# Is akka-http fully compatible with spray-routing dsl?

Tags: scala, spray, spray-dsl, akka-http

1. Is `akka-http` fully compatible with `spray-routing` `DSL`? (my service is fully implemented in `spray-routing` trying to understand how seamless is migration (hopefully just dependency changing)
2. Is it production ready?
3. Can it run on tomcat like `spray` has [Servlet30ConnectorServlet](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-servlet/src/main/scala/spray/servlet/Servlet30ConnectorServlet.scala)
4. Is there an example of how to run `akka-http` on `tomcat` container with similar [Servlet30ConnectorServlet](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-servlet/src/main/scala/spray/servlet/Servlet30ConnectorServlet.scala)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No see https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/746917-5967985951106945028
2. Not of this date yet the only package exist is [akka-http-experimental](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka) but it appears it should be there soon.
3. No
4. Only by using tomcat as a simple start/stop for the akka-http service